# is there and function to convert Int64 value to date in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Is there any method or function to convert int64 "637766000000000000" into date MongoDB[image]

Answer (score 0):

assuming that int64 is a timestamp, you could use `toDate` Mongo aggregation.
[Mongo toDate official docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/)

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5298718/How-to-convert-datetime64-in-javascript)

**Aggregate**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      date: {
        $toDate: {
          $divide: [
            { $subtract: [ "$date", 621355968000000000 ] },
            10000
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cqHJN4fiHkS)

---

**Update**

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      date: {
        $toDate: {
          $divide: [
            { $subtract: [ "$date", 621355968000000000 ] },
            10000
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-ZHpZ19ET91)